# Is it illegal to monetize a Youtube video that contains parts of other YouTube Videos?

Tags: copyright, youtube

If, for example I was making a compilation of the most awesome videos about Yoga on YouTube where I take a small part of each video to make one video, can I monetize that?

Comment: I'm marking this as too broad.  Cmon, what kind of question is this?

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to monetise a compilation. It's specifically in the list of videos you're not allowed to monetise.

> **Examples of content that would NOT be eligible for monetisation**
>
> - You edit together a compilation of content created by others.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/97527